# jQuery Sticky Float keep element stable on resize glitch

Tags: jquery, menu, resize, sticky

I have an element with default, relative positioning that is vertically centered initially with jQuery; when scrolled out of view it becomes fixed positioning and continues to stay in view at the top of the page.

When I re-size the window and scroll to the element that becomes fixed the .offset declaration does not update, therefore causing jerking and skipping in-and-out of view.

How can I fix the script to support window re-sizing with out glitching? Does the .offset need to be replaced with another method or can .offset be redeclared on re-size?

```
// Repeat menuJQfloat on resize
 $(window).resize(function () {
    menuJQfloat();
    navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/khJyz/70/); to see the glitch re-size the page and re-scroll, you will notice that the 'fixed menu' will skip or jerk.

**EDIT: keep in mind, this script works great without the JS vertical centering, but when added it must be causing the nav.offset to miscalculate when the window is a different size from when it was first initialized.**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/khJyz/80/ try that, btw works fine in chrome

Comment: The glitch doesn't appear to have been removed. To see the glitch open your demo, or mine, and zoom in dramatically with your web browser, then scroll down. You will see that skipping and jerking I am talking about.

Comment: still can't repeat the problem

Comment: just fixed a thing jslint was complained for

Comment: the glitch is hard to notice if you don't zoom in/out enough.. try zooming your browser in as much as possible (using CTRL-), then load the demo, then zoom out (using CTRL+) 4 times, then scroll...